# WP Child Theme's style.css working on one site but not on another

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

I  created a child theme of the Wordpress rowling theme.
My style.css contains this:

```
    /*
    Theme Name: MF2017
    Theme URI: 
    Description: rowling Child Theme
    Author: Kathrin Herwig
    Author URI: https://schriftbild.net
    Template: rowling
    Version: 1.0.0
    */
```

and the functions.php this:

```
    <?php
    /**
    * Enqueue scripts and styles.
    */
    function namescript_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
      array('parent-style')
      );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'namescript_scripts' );

     ?>
```

The child theme's css is loaded on my [test-webspace](http://www.schriftbild.net/TEST2/abonnenten/) , the class `.grau: grey` frame around the images is coming from the child theme's css).
But not on the [real website](http://muenchner-feuilleton.de/abonnenten). (.grau is not loaded)

I tried everything, but cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it has to do with access rights / file permissions: When I use the browser tools / styles and click on the child theme style.css, or when I click on the link to the CSS file in the source code, I get to see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /wp-content/themes/MF2017/style.css
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

So the browser is not allowed to load the styesheet. Check the access rights / file permissions of the file and its folder on that server and set it to public.

Comment: exactly! i changed the UNIX access rights to "755" with cyberduck, now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

May be you mess with Theme Name. Child theme name should be "Theme Name child", like "Rowling Child" Follow this code below,

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Rowling Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/rowling-child/
 Description:  Rowling Child Theme
 Author:       Kathrin Herwig
 Author URI:   https://schriftbild.net
 Template:     rowling
 Version:      1.0.0
 Text Domain:  rowling-child
*/
```

for more details check this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: i tried it, but it did not change anything. btw i think you can chose any name you want for the child theme, as long as the lines "description" and "template" are right?